# Why can I not view my Magento site in any Responsiveness checker?

Tags: magento2

Why can I not view my Magento site in any Responsiveness checker?
Can anyone tell me right answer

Answer (score 1):

Your site is running in https. So it will through the below error.

> Refused to display 'https://www.domain.com/' in a frame because it set
>   'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

How to check for more info here:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/secy/secy-xframe.html

Comment: if it is work please let me know?